# Delphi Seattle Webbrowser not working in IOS simulator

Tags: delphi, ios-simulator, delphi-10-seattle

I am trying to run the Webbrowser FM examples that is shipped with Seattle, but it only give me a white screen when I run in iPhone 6 IOS9 simulator.

It's working if I compile for  Win32.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this blog post by TMS Software and see if it's related : 
http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=317 (Fixing the FMX TWebBrowser issue on iOS 9)

"*Linking against iOS 9 introduces the new Application Transport Security feature that enforces a secure network connection. This means that in a default RAD Studio 10 Seattle project, the default TWebBrowser (...) can no longer make a connection to the web.*"

Answer (score 0):

David I also has a detailed post with a temporary (unit next Seattle update) fix for this:

https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/how-to-use-custom-info-plist-xml-to-support-ios-9-s-new-app-transport-security-feature